# How can I use regex to find if a string has 2 specific characters and remove them if they are?

Tags: python, regex

Basically, if I have a string (ex. 'ddbg') python should return 'bg'

I am a little confused as to how to use the regex library for this task.

I have been able to find 1 d and get rid of it... but not 2.

I need to check if a string has only 2 d's and if so remove them.

Comment: What do you want: "Remove  all 'd's? Remove the first two characters? Learn how to use regular expressions to remove patterns? In any case I think the question is not justified as the problem has probably asked and answered a few hundred times before.

Comment: I need to check if a string has only 2 d's and if so remove them.

Comment: Do the d's have to be next to each other?

Comment: Not necessarily... It can also be dbdg and has to return 'bg'.

Comment: So the logic here is that: check if string has two or more _d_s, and get rid of all? What happens with 3 ds? And is `re` a must? why not `s.replace('d', '') if s.count('d') == 2 else s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = "dbdg"
res = re.findall("d", s)
if len(res) == 2:
    s = s.replace("d", "")
```

Comment: @SanjayPatel sure thing. It wouldn't be possible to do it all in one regex operation as it involves different actions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without regex (if you don't have to use regex). Strings are iterable so you can check the count of how many times something shows up in a list. If it shows up twice then use the str type replace method to remove it.

```
    s = "dbdg"
    s = s.replace('d', '') if s.count('d') == 2 else s
```